# How to relate Java source code with the author in sonar

Tags: java, sonarqube

I met a problem.
I want to send a email to every code monkey after analysted project.
This email should contain all links directly linking to sonar page for violations that who made.
I have used [SCM Activity](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/SCM+Activity+Plugin), but I did not find the relation between them.
I tried to query violations from database, but I failed to find out where it is.

I do not have a good idea.

Please help me.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something we are working on with the [Sonar DevCockpit Plugin](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/developer-tools/developer-cockpit/). So if you're patient enough, such feature will become mainstream on Sonar in the near future ;-)